# Anyway to change mount speed?

Tags: terraria

What buffs/debuffs/accessories can affect the mount speed in Terraria, PC version? I've been reading that nothing changes it's speed, but I wonder if there's *anything* that can change the speed, even it's slower or faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not interested in things like hopping on a mount after launching yourself via other means.

Moving through liquids will slow you down - or speed you up in case of the Cute Fishron - but nothing else can change a mount's speed. Even being under the Slow effect is nullified when getting on a mount.